# Derived class's method without constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
public:
        void P(){ cout << "Person P" << endl; }
        virtual void Print(){ cout << "Person Print" << endl; }
        Person(){ cout << "Constructor Person" << endl; }
        virtual ~Person(){ cout << "Dectructor Person" << endl; }
};
class Developer : public Person
{
public:
        void Pi() { cout << "Developer Pi" << endl; }
        void Print() override
        {
                cout << "Developer Print" << endl;
        }
        Developer(){ cout << "Constructor Develoeper" << endl; }
        ~Developer(){ cout << "Dectructor Develoer" << endl; }
};
int main()
{
        Person *p = new Person();
        Developer* d = dynamic_cast<Developer*>(p);
        d->Pi();

        delete p;
        delete d;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor Person
Developer Pi
Dectructor Person
```

Why can I invoke `Developer`'s function `Pi`?

How can invoke `Pi` without `Developer`'s Constructor?

Note that `Pi` is only declared in class `Developer`.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but it will result in **undefined behavior**

Comment: See this very thorough answer for why this is UB: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2474021/3549027

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. Your code has an undefined behavior. If I modify the `main()` function to:

```
int main()
{
    Person *p = new Person();
    Developer* d = dynamic_cast<Developer*>(p);
    assert(d!=0);
    d->Pi();

    delete p;
    delete d;
    return 0;
}
```

Then the assertion `d!=0` is triggered. That shows that the `dynamic_cast` failed. You call `Developer::Pi` on a null pointer, and using your compiler it happens to run fine, probably because `Developer::Pi` does not use `this`.

Comment: @irineau, this is not OP's answer. without `assert` the code works and surprisingly calls `Pi`, the question is why

Answer (score 2):

with `Developer* d = dynamic_cast<Developer*>(p);`
you have `d == nullptr`.

with `d->Pi();`
You invoke undefined behavior:

method are generally *equivalent* to a function which take extra `this` as parameter and as you don't use `this` the method seems to work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It is becuase of dynamic_cast. You are not referring to any variables in the instance, therefor it does not fail.

Accessing any of the virtual methods or accessing anything that would be stored in the object would give access violation.

Answer (score 0):

by stating that d is a pointer to an object of the Developer class you give a hint to the compiler. You also declared void Pi() not to be virtual, therefore the compiler used early binding ( compile time ). That means that the address of the function that is invoked is pinned during compilation, and doesn't need an object to be evaluated ( unlike virtual methods )

When calling d->Pi(), it is the same as you'd call Pi(d) with Pi taking a pointer to a Developer instance. In MFC there is a method called Validate or something like that which uses the very same mechanism to check if your pointer isn't null :)

You don't get a crash on delete d because it is in the standard, that deleting a null pointer is OK, and does nothing ( deleting a dirty pointer is undefined tough ).

Just add the word virtual to the Pi method signature OR add a field to Developer class and try to moddify that field in the Pi method. You will then see the difference ;)