# How do move semantics work with unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I was experimenting with using **unique_ptr** and wrote some simple code to check how it works with move semantics.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class X
{
public:
    X(){}
    ~X() { cout << "Destructor X" << endl; }
    void Print() { cout << "X" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<X> ptr(new X());
    ptr->Print();

    vector<unique_ptr<X>> v;
    v.push_back(move(ptr));
    ptr->Print();
    v.front()->Print();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
X
X
X
Destructor X
```

My expectation was that the original unique_ptr **ptr** would be invalidated after the push_back. But the Print() method is called just fine. What would be the explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> My expectation was that the original unique_ptr ptr would be invalidated after the push_back.

It's set to a null pointer. You can check that by comparing it to `nullptr`.

> But the `Print()` method is called just fine. What would be the explanation for this behavior?

You're calling a member function on a null pointer, which is undefined behaviour. That member function doesn't actually access any data in the class, so it doesn't crash, but it's still undefined behaviour.

You get similar behaviour for this program, it has nothing to do with `unique_ptr`:

```
int main()
{
  X x;
  X* ptr = &x;
  ptr->Print();
  ptr = nullptr;
  ptr->Print();
}
```

It appears to work fine because `X::Print()` doesn't actually read anything from the `this` pointer. If you change the definition of `X::Print()` to access some member data in the class you'll probably get a crash due to dereferencing a null pointer.

See [When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

What you have is plain undefined behavior. If I replace the contents of `main` with the following

```
int main()
{
    unique_ptr<X> ptr;
    ptr->Print();
    cout << (static_cast<bool>(ptr) ? "active\n" : "inactive\n");
}
```

Both gcc and clang still [print](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bb5e05f1f800145)

```
X
inactive
```

You're calling a member function on a `nullptr`, and I'm guessing it just happens to work because the member function doesn't actually make use of the `this` pointer. Change your class definition to:

```
class X
{
    int y = 0;
public:
    X(){}
    ~X() { cout << "Destructor X" << endl; }
    void Print() { cout << "y = " << y << endl; }
};
```

Now your original code should result in a segmentation fault because it'll attempt to dereference `nullptr`.

---

As for your expectation that `unique_ptr` will be invalidated after you move from it, you're absolutely correct. This is guaranteed by the standard.

*§20.8.1/4  [unique.ptr]*

> Additionally, `u` can, upon request, transfer ownership to another unique pointer `u2`. Upon completion of such a transfer, the following postconditions hold:
>   — `u2.p` is equal to the pre-transfer `u.p`,
>   — `u.p` is equal to `nullptr`, and
>   ...

Above `u` & `u2` are `unique_ptr` objects, and `p` is the pointer to the managed object.