# strange behaviour using dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I stumbled upon some strange behaviour while experimenting with dynamic_cast. This is the code i have

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base(){}    
    virtual void output() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
    void output() {}    
    void doDerived_1()
    {
        std::cout << "derived 1\n";
    }
};

struct Derived2: public Base
{ 
    void output() {}
    void doDerived_2()
    {
        std::cout << "derived 2\n";
    }
};     

int main()
{
    Base* base = new Derived1();
    Derived2* der2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(base);
    // der2 = 0
    der2->doDerived_2();
}
```

Even though der2 is equal to 0 doDerived_2() will still be called and any code inside of it will be executed. The code breaks when i call output() function instead.

Can someone explain to me why this works and doesn't break when it clearly should?
Thanks

Comment: Undefined behaviour. But you should check if a cast succeeds before using the result.

Comment: It is undefined behavior to dereference the `nullptr`!

Comment: There was correct answer here, but it was downvoted and deleted...,

Comment: @Agent_L, It's not correct in terms of the standard. I mean explanation is fine, but acting like that's guaranteed to happen without even mentioning that this is undefined behaviour isn't.

Comment: @Agent_L The answer was incorrect. That is why it was down-voted.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha) has a pretty good answer that even takes into account that dereferencing a null pointer has some exceptions to being undefined behaviour. Calling a member function on one always is, however.

Comment: @chris As I remember it did not state that this behavior was guaranteed, it merely explained "why this works and doesn't break". Without addressing the "when it clearly should" issue, though.

Comment: @Agent_L, It gave *one* possible reason for why this works. It really wasn't clear at all in saying the behaviour is not guaranteed, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour, because you are dereferencing a null-pointer.

However, a possible implementation for member function invokation is through the [thiscall calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx), which implicitely passes the object pointer as the first parameter.
If your function does not access any member variables, the `this` pointer is not dereferenced, and the function might execute as expected. It has nothing to do with dynamic_cast.

**Note that this is not guaranteed in the standard**

Example:

```
struct Foo {
    int doIt() {return 42;}
};

int main() {
    Foo *f = NULL;
    std::cout << f->doIt();
}
```

Prints 42 on *some* compilers

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing the null pointer. The behavior of such an operation is undefined. In *this case* it happens to call the method with `this` being the null pointer. However, anything could happen.

If you want an exception to be thrown instead, cast references:

```
Derived2& der2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2&>(*base);
der2.doDerived_2();
```

Alternately, you can use an if-statement to execute some code only if the cast succeeds:

```
if (Derived2* der2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(base)) {
    der2->doDerived_2();
}
```

Comment: I know I should check for pointer validity before calling any of the member methods. I was just confused that when the pointer is 0 it still worked. @king_nak example was a good explanation for this behaviour.