# Invoking static method through an uninitialized pointer

Tags: c++

I came upon some old code which uses a rather strange method for calling a static function of a class:

**Class definition and implementation**

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  ...
  static MyClass *GetFromString(const char *string);
  ...
};


MyClass *MyClass::GetFromString(const char *string)
{
   ...
}
```

**Calling of GetFromString in the old code**

```
  MyClass *pClass = pClass->GetFromString("TEST");
```

**IMO the proper way would be this**

```
  pClass = MyClass::GetFromString("TEST");
```

In the first method it looks as if we dereference an uninitialized this pointer, but as the `GetFromString` method is static, the this pointer is actually not needed and the code works.

What does the standard say ? Is the first method correct or could it lead to undefined behaviour with some compilers ?

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha) because I explicitly mean *static* member functions.