# Checking whether (this == nullptr) in a class method

Tags: c++, null

I would like to replace code like this:

```
if ((obj != nullptr) && obj->is_valid())
```

with

```
if (obj->is_valid())
```

where

```
class Obj {
    bool is_valid() {
        if (this == nullptr)
            return false;
        // some more logic ...
    }
    ...
};
```

Obviously there are 2 conditions:

1. `obj` is always accessed via pointer
2. `Obj::is_valid()` is never virtual

This is based on the fact, that a non-virtual method accepts `this` as its 1-st argument, so that

```
obj->is_valid();
```

is rewritten as

```
Obj::is_valid(obj);
```

While this code does work as expected with gcc-5.4.0, my question is whether this is a legitimate C++ code, that will be interpreted / optimized correctly by other (older / newer) C++ compilers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It's going to do what you expect it to do nearly everywhere (without any optimization at least), but there's no guarantee, as it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Blaze It won't on newer versions of gcc with optimization enabled. That's why answers belong in the answer section, not in comments, so we can downvote misinformation like that.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about optimization. I'll add that to the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't.

```
if (this == nullptr)
```

It would not provide any security as [calling a member function (method) on a null pointer is undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Null_pointers) in the first place. This is bringing a sensation of security without the security, which is worse than nothing.

Comment: I found this on [cppreference: Null pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Null_pointers): _dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior_.

Comment: While reading (and upvoting) your answer, I was searching for something like an "authoritative" source... (and thought, it might be worth to provide the link to cppreference I found).