# Does 'this' pointer in bind C++ really matters?

Tags: c++11

I am trying to experiment bind in C++. Basically I have two class - Invokee. The invokee class registers a test handler that needs to be invoked upon some callbacks. The method here is -

```
 void RegisterTestHandler(int id, TestFunction handler, std::string summary, std::string details);
```

Similarly, I have another method that actually invokes what has been registered -

```
void callHandler(int id);
```

Another class Test which has a function that needs to be invoked on callHandler.

```
unsigned int globalReset(int val);
```

In the main function, I am doing the nullptr for the second parameter in the bind. However, it still works and I don't get any crashes. Is it something working because of the compiler optimisation or undefined behaviour or it is something to do with bind concept.

Here is the entire experimental code.

// main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
#include "invokee.h"
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

// beautify using clang-format in Vscode.


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto *invokeTest = new Invokee();
    Test *test = new Test();

    std::string summary = "global reset summary";
    std::string details = "global reset details";

    //Basically there are two object from different class - InvokeTest --> does the registration of the handler.
    // Now the InvokeTest has to call the member function of class object - Test.
    // ?? How it can do - it can do using bind - basically, the this pointer of Test class is available to invokeTest
    // therefore invokeTest can simply invoke the member function of test object.
    // until the test point is valid, it can use it to invoke the method of it ?? --> Is it really correct?

    delete(test);  //experiment deleted the test pointer.
    test= nullptr;  // explicity set to nullptr
    // still it works?? how come ??

    invokeTest->RegisterTestHandler(1, std::bind(&Test::globalReset, test, std::placeholders::_1), summary, details);
    invokeTest->callHandler(1);

    

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the invokee.cpp -

```
#include "invokee.h"

void Invokee::RegisterTestHandler(int id, TestFunction handler, std::string summary, std::string details)
{

    this->handlers[id] = handler;
    this->summary[id] = summary;
    this->details[id] = details;
}

void Invokee::callHandler(int id)
{
    auto handler = handlers.find(id);
    if (handler != handlers.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Found the handler --" << std::endl;
        handler->second(1);
    }
}
```

Here is the test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

unsigned int Test::globalReset(int val)
{

    std::cout << "global Reset invoked" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha)

Comment: tl;dr it's undefined behavior. Your C++ compiler happens to be able to statically determine which function should be called and is doing it anyway. It never checks for `nullptr` because it doesn't have to. But the behavior is undefined. It may not work on someone else's computer, or someone else's compiler, or it may not work tomorrow on your own machine when you change an unrelated line in a file far away.