# Null pointer in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing class members on a NULL pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669742/accessing-class-members-on-a-null-pointer)

```
#include<iostream.h>
class X{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        X() {}
        void func() {
            cout<<"In func()"<<endl;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    X *x=NULL;
    x->func();
    return 0;
}
```

I am really surprised with the o/p ,can anyone please explain me how x can access func().

Comment: It's undefined behavior. There is no explanation - anything an happen.

Comment: @Bo - well, there *is* an explanation, just not in terms of the C++ standard. More in terms of how C++ is normally compiled. +1 that comment anyway, for undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x->func()` just means you're calling `func` with the `this` pointer being `x`. So in this case it's `NULL`

From `func` you're not using any member variable so you're not using `this`.

Anyway, this is bad and as pointed out by Bo Persson, undefined behavior. You should not be doing this.