# Dereferencing a NULL pointer in C++

Tags: c++, g++, null-pointer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing class members on a NULL pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669742/accessing-class-members-on-a-null-pointer)

I know dereferencing a NULL pointer crashes the program or give undefined behavior. But following program consistently prints `This is a car` how many ever times I run. Checked in Linux (g++) and AIX (xlc++).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
public:
    void display(){ cout << "This is a car" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Car *c = NULL;
    c->display();
}
```

When I add one data member for the class and try to print the value of that, then the program crashes.

```
class Car
{
     int i;
 public:
     void display(){ cout << "This is a car" << i << endl; }
};
```

So it seems it is fine to dereference a NULL pointer and call a member function which does not access a data member of the class. Is that really an undefined behavior?

Comment: Yes, it is really undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour is not "guaranteed to not do what the user expects". So, no, it's not fine to dereference a null pointer. Why? *Because there's no sane reason you would want to*.