# Checking for this == NULL in a member-function without invoking undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, recursion, static-methods

Suppose I have a C++ class and I would like to have a recursive member-function which is called with instances items of the class,  for example

```
// the eplicit "this" is just for clarity in the following code:
void recursivePrintTree(){
    (if this == NULL){ // We are "out" of the tree
        return; 
    }
    cout << this->val;
    (this->leftSon)->printBinaryTree();
    (this->rightSon)->printBinaryTree();
}
```

The problem is of course invoking undefined behaviour by calling printBinary with NULL in the first place! so I would like to avoid this, and as far as I know I have at least three ways of doing so:

1) Using static member functions, which get an explicit this-type argument that can be safely checked. this is actually what I did so far but because it's a very recursive implementation, almost all of the member-functions get coded as static. That's not very good, right?

2) checking the stop condition for the *next* node before having another recursive call with a NULL pointer possibly as "this". This is a much less natural form of writing and actually checks other items other that This. and I would like to avoid it.

3) Using default dummy values. Tried it, felt it's not really saving me any special-case-treatment, but that may have been just because of the Generic-ness of my tree.

I have really been fussing around this matter for a while now so would appreciate any good advice.

Comment: `this` can not be `NULL`, because at least you have an object which is calling that method.

Comment: ... what syntax is this?

Comment: Write `if (!this)` instead. It's more idiomatic.

Comment: or instead check for next, not for this `if (!this->next)`

Comment: The 2nd solution is a right way, no matter it seam weird or not.

Comment: @jrok First, `this` can never be null, which is the crux of his question.  And second, the only acceptable way of checking for a null pointer is to compare it with `NULL` or `0` (or `nullptr`, in C++11).  Implicit conversions are confusing, and should generally be avoided.

Comment: @Jiwan: Take a step back.  The root problem is that he is walking a tree, not a node.  And the tree walking code doesn't belong in `Node`, but in `Tree` (which, of course, knows something about `Node`, since it has `Node`s).

Comment: And why has anyone voted the question down?  It looks like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: @JamesKanze I tried to be funny. Looks like a pretty failed attempt, then. :P And by the way, you don't object to `if (p)` where p is a pointer, or do you?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong.

Instead of checking for NULL in `this`, you can check for NULL in `this->next` so you can avoid calling the method for NULL pointers in the first place.

That is, instead of:

```
void printBinaryTree() {
    if(this == NULL){
       return;
    }
    cout << this->val;
    this->next->printBinaryTree();
}
```

Do this:

```
void printBinaryTree() {
    cout << this->val;
    if(this->next)
        this->next->printBinaryTree();
}
```

BTW. this is a linked list.

Comment: I think he knows that.  That's why he's asking the question: he wants to know the best way of avoiding the null `this` pointer.

Comment: Thanks. The solution you kindly suggested is what I mentioned in option 2, but then I have to check for NULL outside the function before calling it the first time. Imagine having a pointer to a tree which very possibly be empty. than that pointer is not a node but a null, and I would need to check for it every first invoking of printTree(). I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

The second solution is the only solution *if* you want to
navigate from within the node structure.  The usual solution,
however, is to distinguish between nodes and the tree, and the
navigation code is a member of the tree object, not the node.
At most, the node has a function to return the next pointer. 
This means that the naviagtion functions would take a pointer to
the nodes; your `printBinaryTree` might be something like:

```
void
BinaryTree::print( Node const* node )
{
    if ( node != NULL ) {
        node->print();
        print( node->next() );
    }
}
```

Or you can use the visitor pattern, which separates the tree
walking code from the actions at each node.

Comment: I agree that the visitor pattern seam legit for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try out your implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

class BinaryTree {
    public:
        BinaryTree(int value, BinaryTree * left, BinaryTree * right) : value_(value), left_(left), right_(right) {}

        void printBinaryTree(int depth = 0) {

            for ( int i = 0; i < depth; i++ ) std::cout << "  ";

            if ( this == NULL ) {
                std::cout << "Null node, returning..." << std::endl;
                return;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << value_ << std::endl;
            }

            left_->printBinaryTree(depth+1);
            right_->printBinaryTree(depth+1);
        }

    private:
        int value_;
        BinaryTree * left_;
        BinaryTree * right_;
};

int main() {
    BinaryTree leaf(0,NULL,NULL);
    BinaryTree top(1,&leaf, &leaf);

    top.printBinaryTree();

    return 0;
}
```

If we make this run, we get an output that looks like this:

```
1
  0
    Null node, returning...
    Null node, returning...
  0
    Null node, returning...
    Null node, returning...
```

The reason why this works is explained here: [Accessing class members on a NULL pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669742/accessing-class-members-on-a-null-pointer)

However, as per C++ standard, doing this is undefined behaviour. As in, this works only because the implementation of your, or in this case mine, compiler is able to make this work. It is not a guarantee of any kind, and this reduces your portability, and could even stop working if you ever need to update your compiler!

There are a bunch of alternatives to this. You already list some, though I must say I dislike the static implementation because it doesn't make really sense from a design standpoint, and makes all your code a mess. An additional solution could be to make the `printBinaryTree` function virtual, and define the leaf nodes as a child class of the tree. This is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class BinaryTree {
    public:
        BinaryTree(int value, BinaryTree * left, BinaryTree * right) : value_(value), left_(left), right_(right) {}

        virtual void printBinaryTree(int depth = 0) {

            for ( int i = 0; i < depth; i++ ) std::cout << "  ";

            std::cout << value_ << std::endl;

            left_->printBinaryTree(depth+1);
            right_->printBinaryTree(depth+1);
        }

        int getValue() { return value_; }

    private:
        int value_;
        BinaryTree * left_;
        BinaryTree * right_;
};

class BinaryTreeLeaf : public BinaryTree {
    public:
        BinaryTreeLeaf(int value) : BinaryTree(value, NULL, NULL) {}

        virtual void printBinaryTree(int depth=0) {
            for ( int i = 0; i < depth; i++ ) std::cout << "  ";

            std::cout << getValue() << std::endl;
        }

};

int main() {
    BinaryTreeLeaf leaf(0);
    BinaryTree top(1,&leaf, &leaf);

    top.printBinaryTree();

    return 0;
}
```

The output here, as desired, is:

```
1
  0
  0
```