# calling a function through a pointer - access violation reading location

Tags: c++, pointers, access-violation

I have a function that returns a `Customer` object (not pointer) like this:

```
Customer CustomerList::retrieve(const int index) const{
        if (index<1 || index>size)
                return false;
        else{
                Node *cur = find(index);
                return (cur->data);
        }
}
```

This function gets a `Customer` object from a `CustomerList`(which is a linkedlist).

I'm trying to manipulate the `Customer` in the list with following function(this function adds an `Account` to the `Customer` object.)

```
list.retrieve(i).addAccount(acc);
```

However after this function call, `Customer` object in `CustomerList` doesn't change. I assume that the reason is I return a copy of a `Customer` object, not the object itself.

So in order to return the adress of Customer and manipulate it correctly, i make the following changes to my function.

```
Customer* CustomerList::retrieve(const int index) const{
        if (index<1 || index>size)
                return false;
        else{
                Node *cur = find(index);
                return &(cur->data);
        }
}
```

And call the manipulating function like that:

```
list.retrieve(i)->addAccount(acc);
```

But it gives me a **"Access violation reading location 0x00000044."** error. What I want to learn is:

1. Why doesn't it manipulate the `Customer` object in first place? Is my assumption right?
2. After I change my functions and function calls, why does it gives me the error I mentioned above?

Comment: How are you doing `return false;` when your return type is `Customer`? Does it make sense to convert from a `bool` to a `Customer`?

Comment: have you checked if `cur` is NULL?

Comment: Show us a definition of Customer class

Comment: `return false`? Well, that would become zero, although I'm not convinced you can get that to compile. But calling a function from a member that is zero won't work.

Comment: Access violation reading 0x00000044 doesn't mean null pointer deref. Looks like you're trying to dereference a pointer (?) that points to this address (0x00000044)

Comment: @maverik: That just means whatever OP is trying to access is at a 44-byte offset from 0, which I find to be pretty close.

Comment: @Xeo, hm... may be you're right here. Anyway we need to see Node class

Comment: @Chethan, I don't think it is related with a NULL check because it is works normally at first state.

Comment: `private: 
 struct Node{
  Customer data;
  Node *next;
  Node *prev;
 };`

Comment: @BurakÖzmen, is it easier to check for NULL rather than guessing why it crashes?

Comment: It looks like you are returning `false` which is `0` and then when you call `addAccount` it is accessing a member at an offset `44` bytes from `0` which is what your `this` pointer will be. You need to not return `false` and check the return from `retrieve` is not `NULL` before you use it. This is very similar although not identical to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669742/accessing-class-members-on-a-null-pointer

Comment: Actually it was about NULL check and range check. Never start your checking from 0 when first item has an index of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't it manipulate the Customer object in first place? Is my assumption right?

As you say, you're returning a copy and manipulating that, leaving the one in the list untouched.

> After I change my functions and function calls, why does it gives me the error I mentioned above?

Almost certainly because of this:

```
return false;
```

That will return a null pointer if the index is out of bounds. If that's the behaviour you want, then you'll need to check before dereferencing the pointer:

```
if (Customer * c = list.retrieve(i)) {
    c->addAccount(acc);
} else {
    // handle the error?
}
```

and, out of politeness, you should return something that looks more like a null pointer such as `nullptr`, `NULL`, or `0`.

It might be a better idea to throw an exception (perhaps `std::range_error`); then the caller can assume that the pointer is valid if the function returns. In that case, it might also be better to return a reference rather than a pointer, giving code very much like your original example:

```
Customer & CustomerList::retrieve(const int index) const{
    if (index<1 || index>size)
            throw std::range_error("Customer index out of range");
    else{
            Node *cur = find(index);
            return (cur->data);
    }
}

list.retrieve(i).addAccount(acc); // Does exactly what you'd expect
```

I might also consider moving the range checks into the `find` function, if that seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why doesn't it manipulate the Customer object in first place?

Yes you are right. by defualt its retuned `by value` not by reference so original object in List is not geting modified.

> 1. After I change my functions and function calls, why does it gives me the error I mentioned above?

I think you need to share the code of `addAccount` Method. the problem may be inside it. 
Considering then with original code `return by value` it was working corectly (without exception).