# Why is no NullReferenceException raised?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have shown this to several colleagues and no one has an explanation.
I ran into this by pure chance, as I thought I spotted a bug in our code, but was surprised to see that the code actually ran.
Here is a simplified version.
This has been done with XE-2.

Everyone I have spoke to so far, also expects that a NullReferenceException should be thrown.

```
 TUnexplainable = class(TObject)
  public
    function Returns19: Integer;
  end;

function TUnexplainable.Returns19: Integer;
begin
  Result := 19;
end;
```

The following test should NEVER work, but it runs succesfully. Why is no NullReferenceException thrown????

```
procedure TTestCNCStep.ShouldNeverEverWorkV4;
var
  Impossible: TUnexplainable;
  Int1: Integer;
begin
  Impossible := nil;
  Int1 := Impossible.Returns19; // A Null Reference Exception should ocurr here!!! Instead the method Returns19 is actually invoked!!!!
  Check(Int1 = 19);
end;
```

[image: Test resuts]

Comment: The code does not reference any object fields on the heap, so no need to use the Self reference.

Comment: See also, [the C++ version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/669774/33732)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A non-static class method is compiled into a standalone function with a hidden `Self` parameter.  So, your code is essentially doing the following, from the compiler's perspective:

```
//function TUnexplainable.Returns19: Integer;
function TUnexplainable_Returns19(Self: TUnexplainable): Integer;
begin
  Result := 19;
end;

//procedure TTestCNCStep.ShouldNeverEverWorkV4;
procedure TTestCNCStep_ShouldNeverEverWorkV4(Self: TTestCNCStep);
var
  Impossible: TUnexplainable;
  Int1: Integer;
begin
  Impossible := nil;
  Int1 := TUnexplainable_Returns19(Impossible);
  Check(Int1 = 19);
end;
```

As you can see, `Returns19()` is not referencing `Self` for anything, so there is no reason for a nil pointer error to occur.

Change your code to do something with `Self`, and then you will see the error you are expecting:

```
type
  TUnexplainable = class(TObject)
  public
    Number: Integer;
    function ReturnsNumber: Integer;
  end;

function TUnexplainable.ReturnsNumber: Integer;
begin
  Result := Number;
end;

procedure TTestCNCStep.ShouldNeverEverWorkV4;
var
  Impossible: TUnexplainable;
  Int1: Integer;
begin
  Impossible := nil;
  Int1 := Impossible.ReturnsNumber; // An EAccessViolation exception will now occur here!!!
end;
```

> I have shown this to several colleagues and no one has an explanation.

I would be very worried working with a group of colleagues (assuming they are programmers) who do not understand the basics of how class methods and the `Self` parameter actually work, and how calling a class method via a nil pointer can avoid a null pointer error.  This is like *Object-Oriented Programming 101* kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. Coming from c++ and c# I am quite sure this would have lead to an exception.
One difficulty I have had with Delphi is that I found no recent books covering the language. So even if you want to learn Delphi more in depth there is barely any new material available.

Comment: What I described is how C++ works, too. However, C# is different, as .NET is a managed environment that checks object pointers and method calls for validity.

Comment: @santiagoIT - the behaviour involved here is not new to Delphi.  It is a fundamental part of the behaviour of the runtime code produced by Delphi since version 1.0.  e.g. the "Free" method on TObject explicitly relies on the ability to call methods with a NIL object reference.   The excellent Delphi in a Nutshell is still highly relevant and useful for this kind of thing.  Also worth noting is that this behaviour is limited only to non-virtual methods.  Try the exact same thing with **Returns19** declared as virtual and calling that with a NIL object reference **will** result in an exception.

Comment: @Deltics: "*this behaviour is limited only to non-virtual methods*" - very true.  The act of calling a `virtual` or `dynamic` method requires access to the object's vtable/dispatch table, which can only be reached via a *valid* object pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Your method never references the `Self` pointer, so it happens to work.

Unlike C#, Delphi does not validate the `Self` (`this` in C#) pointer automatically.