# Why can an uninitialized pointer access a class member?

Tags: c++

```
class C {
    public:
    C(int x):
    _x(x){}
    void print(){
        std::cout<<_x<<std::endl;
    }    
    int _x;
};

int main(){
C* c;
c->print(); // print 0 !
return 0;
}
```

c is a pointer of type C, but it is pointed to nothing ! so why `c->print()` works ?

for example if I try

```
int* p;
```

I can't compile because am trying to point to nothing and compiler stops me.

I should use

```
int* p = nullptr;
```

or point to a given reference. should it be the same with a defined type C ? instead of 'int' I use 'C' so why different results?

Comment: terms like "works" have no meaning in the land of undefined behavior

Comment: Because Undefined Behavior can do *anything*, including producing seemingly-sensible results.

Comment: Have a read of [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: Add to your compiler `-Wall -Werror` or `/W4 /WX` and compiler will report an error: https://godbolt.org/z/6eKdKW54a

Comment: [Look at the results here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c06e7055d002967d).  A segmentation fault.

Comment: Pretty close to a duplicate here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669742/accessing-class-members-on-a-null-pointer

Comment: Crashes on my machine.  **Undefined behavior**.  Go figure!  C++ is not a nanny language, it presumes you know what you are doing, and if you give bad code to the compiler, then there are no guarantees as to the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behaviour. This means that you have done something illegal (indirection through an uninitialized pointer) but the compiler is not required to catch it and the program may appear to work at runtime, but such behaviour is never guaranteed.